Only shows NULL when using the variable which set with Scope_Identity() on JOIN statements in a stored procedure
After INSERT and setting a variable (@scopeID) with SCOPE_IDENTITY(), when I try to JOIN tables with @scopeID, I can only see the value of @scopeID, and other variables are NULL.
INSERT INTO InsertTable (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (2, @parameter1, @parameter2);

SET @scopeID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

SELECT @var1 = a.var1, @var2 = b.var2, @var3 = b.var3
FROM SetTable AS a
LEFT JOIN JoinTable(=InsertTable) AS b ON a.var4 = b.var4 AND b.scopeID = @scopeID
WHERE b.scopeID = @scopeID;

SELECT @var1, @var2, @var3, @scopeID;

If I set @scopeID to a specific value (such as 12345), it shows all of the variables.
What is the cause and how can I deal with this error?
I'd like to see values about all variables selected.

WHERE b.scopeID = @scopeID turns this query into an INNER JOIN, so nothing is shown unless there's a match. b.scopeID will be NULL if the LEFT JOIN condition fails, which makes WHERE b.scopeID = @scopeID reject those rows. @scopeID has a non-null value, but even if both the field and @scopeID were NULL, the comparison would still fail. NULL isn't equal to NULL

JoinTable(b) is same as InsertTable. It returns right scope_identity() value, but it returns NULL when trying to join tables..

I already explained why that happens. If the tables are the same, why did you use different names? Post the actual names

Sorry, that's my mistake. I think it can't capture scopeID data in real time. Thank you for your help.

Please post a realistic example that actually reproduces the problem. We have no guarantee that there are any matches. The query joins on a.var4 = b.var4. There's no mention of var4 in the original INSERT which means it's either NULL and thus can't match anything, or that it's one of the col1,col2,col3 columns.

WHERE b.scopeID = @scopeID turns this query into an INNER JOIN, so nothing is shown unless there's a match. b.scopeID will be NULL if the LEFT JOIN condition fails, which makes WHERE b.scopeID = @scopeID fail on all those rows. NULL = NULL fails in SQL's 3-valued logic and @scopeID already has a non-null value.
A better option would be to use the OUTPUT clause to get the new IDs into a table variable and JOIN with that. SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns the latest generated value in the transaction, no matter where it came from. The OUTPUT clause though works only on the target table and even better, can work with any number of inserted rows:
declare @newIDs table(scopeID bigint PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO InsertTable (col1, col2, col3)
OUTPUT inserted.scopeID into @newIDs
VALUES 
    (2, @parameter1, @parameter2);

SELECT a.var1, b.var2, b.var3, b.scopeID
FROM SetTable AS a
LEFT JOIN InsertTable AS b ON a.var4 = b.var4 
INNER JOIN @newIDs c on c.scopeID=b.scopeID;

This will return the same result as SELECT @var1, @var2, @var3, @scopeID; if only one row is inserted. It will also work if multiple values are inserted, with eg:
INSERT INTO InsertTable (col1, col2, col3)
OUTPUT inserted.scopeID into @newIDs
VALUES 
    (2, @parameter1, @parameter2),
    (3, @parameter3, @parameter4);


You state: "SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns the latest generated value in the transaction, no matter where it came from." From @@IDENTITY: "@@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the value only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope." OUTPUT is a far more useful tool as it handles multiple rows, can output before and after values, ... .

@HABO you're repeating the same things I said with different words. My intention wasn't to explain how SCOPE_IDENTITY works but how OUTPUT helps in this case

It was your "no matter where it came from" that I questioned. Scope_Identity returns values from the same scope ("A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, if two statements are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.") while @@Identity will returns values from any scope, e.g. a trigger lurking deep in the background.

Thank you for the answer. I tried this way, and scope_identity() value is inserted to newIDs successfully.
But when  trying to execute the JOIN statement, b.scopeID shows NULL.
b.scopeID exists in b. I don't know why and it seems it can't capture scopeID data in real time. Thank you for your help, though :)

@yelimlee post a realistic example, something others can execute to reproduce the problem.
